# Проблемы с реализацией поиска элементов по ListView

Tags: java, android, listview, arraylist, android-edittext

На разметке активности, есть `Listview` с множественным выбором. Выбранные эдементы обрабатываются следующим образом:

```
ArrayList<String> list = new ArrayList<String>;
list.add("Maria");
list.add("Estonia");
String selectedItems = " ";
    ingridients_lv.setOnItemClickListener(new AdapterView.OnItemClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int position, long id) {
            SparseBooleanArray sp=ingridients_lv.getCheckedItemPositions();

            selectedItems="";
            for(int i=0;i < list.size();i++){
                    if(sp.get(i)) {
                        selectedItems += list.get(i) + " ";
                    }
            }
        }
    });
```

Так же есть `EditText`, по символам введенным в него ведется поиск совпадающих элементов в `ListView` это происходит следующим образом:

```
    inputSearch.addTextChangedListener(new TextWatcher() {
        @Override
        public void beforeTextChanged(CharSequence s, int start, int count, int after) {

        }

        @Override
        public void onTextChanged(CharSequence s, int start, int before, int count) {
            SearchActivity.this.adapter.getFilter().filter(s);
        }

        @Override
        public void afterTextChanged(Editable s) {

        }
    });
```

Но после ввода символов в `EditText` и выбора подходящего элемента, в переменную `selectedItems` поступает не выбранное значение поля, а значение поля выбранного индекса `list`.
Например: поле `Maria` имеет индекс 0, а `Estonia` индекс 1. При вводе в `inputSearch` символа 'E' в ListView остается только `Estonia`, но при выборе `Estonia` в пременную `selectedItems` попадает значение `Maria`. Как это исправить?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

После фильтрации в `Listview` остаётся меньше элементов и индексы сдвигаются.
Можно получить данные выбранных элементов через сам `Listview`

```
    public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int position, long id) {
        SparseBooleanArray sp=ingridients_lv.getCheckedItemPositions();

        selectedItems="";
        for(int i=0;i < list.size();i++){
                if(sp.get(i)) {
                    selectedItems += parent.getItemAtPosition(i) + " ";
                }
        }
    }
```

Comment: Благодарю. Сейчас протестирую

Comment: Спасибо, помогло